# Why I am getting error message in df['smiles'] command

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python, I don't know why I am getting error message when I am giving df['smiles'] command in df dataframe. But the other column is perfectly appearing by  df['Name'] command. Can anyone please help me point out the error I am making. Thank you.

Where is the problem?

I am new to python, I don't know why I am getting error message when I am giving df['smiles'] command in df dataframe. But the other column is perfectly appearing by  df['Name'] command. Can anyone please help me point out the error I am making. Thank you.

Where is the problem?

`````
    import pandas as pd
        
    from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
        
    from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors3D
        
    import ternary
        
    from ternary.helpers import simplex_iterator
        
    import numpy as np
        
    import matplotlib
        
    from rdkit import Chem
        
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
    get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline') 
        
    df = pd.read_csv('npsmiles.csv', encoding='cp1252')
        
    df
    ````

Name    smiles
0   Taxol   O1[C@@H]2C[C@H](O)[C@@]3([C@H]([C@H](OC(=O)c4...
1   Actinonin   OC[C@H]1N(CCC1)C(=O)[C@@H](NC(=O)[C@H](CCCCC)...
2   Discodermolide  O1[C@@H](C[C@H](O)\C=C/[C@@H]([C@H](O)[C@H](\...
3   Validamycin     O1[C@H](CO)[C@@H](O)[C@H](O)[C@@H](O)[C@@H]1O...
4   Monensin    O1[C@@H]([C@H](C[C@@H](C)[C@]1(O)CO)C)[C@@H]1...
5   Calyculin A     P(O[C@H]1[C@H](O[C@@]2(O[C@@H](C\C=C\c3nc(oc3...
6   Coformycin  O1[C@H](CO)[C@@H](O)[C@@H](O)[C@@H]1n1c2NC=[N...
7   Arglabin    O1[C@H]2[C@@H](CC[C@@]3(O[C@]34[C@@H]2C(=CC4)...
8   Mizoribine  O1[C@H](CO)[C@@H](O)[C@@H](O)[C@@H]1n1cnc(C(=...
9   Forskolon   O1[C@@]2(C)[C@@](O)([C@@]3([C@@H]([C@H](O)[C@...
10  SQ 26180    S(=O)(=O)([O-])N1C[C@](OC)(NC(=O)C)C1=O
11  Cephamycin C    S1[C@H]2N(C(C(=O)[O-])=C(C1)COC(=O)N)C(=O)[C@...
12  Avermectin B1a  O1[C@@H]2C[C@@]3(O[C@H]([C@H](CC)C)[C@H](C=C3...
13  Adriamycin  O1[C@@H](C)[C@@H](O)[C@@H]([NH3+])C[C@@H]1O[C...
14  Phorbol myristate acetate   O=C1[C@]2(O)[C@@H](C=C1C)[C@]1(O)[C@H]([C@H]3...
15  Thienamycin     S(CC[NH3+])C=1C[C@H]2N(C=1C(=O)[O-])C(=O)[C@@...
16  Cyclosporin A   O=C1N(C)[C@@H]([C@H](O)[C@@H](C\C=C\C)C)C(=O)...
17  FK506   O1[C@H](/C(=C/[C@H]2C[C@@H](OC)[C@H](O)CC2)/C...
18  Trapoxin B  O1C[C@H]1C(=O)CCCCC[C@@H]1NC(=O)[C@@H]2N(CCC2...
19  Vincristine     O(C)c1cc2N([C@@H]3[C@]4([C@H]5[NH+](CC=C[C@@]...
20  Colchicine  O(C)C1=CC=C2c3c(cc(OC)c(OC)c3OC)CC[C@H](NC(=O...
21  Trichostatin A  O=C([C@@H](\C=C(\C=C\C(=O)N[O-])/C)C)c1ccc(N(...
22  Fumagillin  O1[C@](C)([C@H]2[C@H](OC)[C@H](OC(=O)\C=C\C=C...
23  Staurosporine   O1[C@H]2n3c4c(c5c(CNC5=O)c5c6c(n(c45)[C@]1(C)...
24  Erythromycin A  O1[C@H](CC)[C@](O)(C)[C@H](O)[C@@H](C)C(=O)[C...
25  Streptomycin    O1[C@@H](CO)[C@H](O)[C@@H](O)[C@H]([NH2+]C)[C...
26  Penicillin G    S1[C@H]2N([C@@H](C(=O)[O-­-])C1(C)C)C(=O)[C@H]...
27  Sperguallin     O=C(N[C@@H](O)C(=O)NCCCC[NH2+]CCC[NH3+])C[C@@...
28  Rapamycin   O1[C@@H](CC(=O)[C@@H](\C=C(/C)\[C@@H](O)[C@@H...
29  Echinocandin B  Oc1ccc(cc1)[C@H](O)[C@@H](O)[C@@H]1NC(=O)[C@H...
30  Ginkgolide B    O1[C@@H]2[C@@](O)([C@]34O[C@@H]5OC(=O)[C@H](O...
31  Vancomycin  Clc1c2Oc3cc4[C@@H](NC(=O)[C@@H](NC(=O)[C@H](N...
32  Amphotericin B  O1[C@@H](C)[C@H](C)[C@H](O)[C@H](\C=C\C=C\C=C...
33  Radicicol   Clc1c2c(C(O[C@@H](C[C@H]3O[C@@H]3/C=C\C=C\C(=...
34  Salicylihalamide A  O1[C@H](C[C@@H](O)[C@H](C\C=C\Cc2c(C1=O)c(O)c...
35  Telomestatin    S1C2=N[C@H](c3oc(c(n3)-c3oc(c(n3)-c3occ(n3)-c...
36  Rifamycin B     O1c2c3c4c(c(O)c2C)c(O)c(NC(=O)/C(=C\C=C\[C@H]...
37  Apoptolidin     O1[C@@H](C[C@H](OC)[C@@H](O)CC\C=C(\C=C\[C@H]...
38  Midecamycin A1  O1[C@@H](C\C=C\C=C\[C@H](O)[C@@H](C[C@H](CC=O...
39  Zaragozic acid A    O1[C@@]2(C(=O)[O-])[C@](O)(C(O)=O)[C@H](O[C@]...
40  Talaromycin B   O1C[C@H](CO)[C@@H](O)C[C@]12OC[C@@H](CC2)CCS
41  Spongistatin 1  ClC(\C=C\[C@@H](O)CC(C[C@H]1O[C@H]2[C@H](O)[C...
42  Brevetoxin B    O1[C@@H]2[C@H](O[C@@]3([C@H](O[C@@H]4[C@H](O[...
43  Quinine     O(C)c1cc2c(nccc2[C@@H](O)[C@H]2[N@@H+]3C[C@@H...
44  Mycobactin S    O1C[C@H](N=C1c1ccccc1O)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN([O-...
45  Duocarmycin A   O(C)c1c(OC)c2[nH]c(cc2cc1OC)C(=O)N1C=2[C@]3([...
46  Bleomycin A2    [S+](CCCNC(=O)c1nc(sc1)-c1nc(sc1)CCNC(=O)[C@@...
47  Brefeldin A     O1[C@H](CCC\C=C\[C@H]2[C@@H](C[C@@H](O)C2)[C...
48  Cytochalasin B  O1[C@@]23[C@@H]([C@H](C)C(=C)[C@@H](O)[C@@H]2...
49  Epothilone A    s1cc(nc1C)\C=C(/C)\[C@H]1OC(=O)C[C@H](O)C(C)(...
50  Lactacystin     S(C(=O)[C@@]1(NC(=O)[C@H](C)[C@@H]1O)[C@@H](O...
51  Calicheamicin 1     Ic1c(C)c(C(S[C@@H]2[C@H](O[C@@H](ON[C@H]3[C@H...
52  Artemisinin     O1[C@@H]2O[C@@]3(OO[C@]24[C@@H](CC[C@H]([C@@H...
53  Compactin   O1[C@@H](C[C@@H](O)CC1=O)CC[C@@H]1[C@@H]2C(C=...
54  Lipstatin   O1[C@@H](C[C@@H](OC(=O)[C@@H](NC=O)CC(C)C)C\C...
55  Pseudomonic acid A  O1[C@@H](C[C@H]2CO[C@@H](C\C(=C\C(OCCCCCCCCC(...
56  Daptomycin  O1[C@H](C)[C@H](NC(=O)[C@@H](NC(=O)[C@H](NC(=...
57  Bestatin    O=C(N[C@@H](CC(C)C)C(=O)[O-])[C@@H](O)[C@H]([...
58  Plaunotol   OC/C(=C\CC\C(=C\CO)\C)/CC\C=C(\CC\C=C(\C)/C)/C
59  Geldanamycin    O(C)C1=C2C[C@H](C[C@H](OC)[C@H](O)[C@H](\C=C(...

    'df['Name']'

0                         Taxol
1                     Actinonin
2                Discodermolide
3                   Validamycin
4                      Monensin
5                   Calyculin A
6                    Coformycin
7                      Arglabin
8                    Mizoribine
9                     Forskolon
10                     SQ 26180
11                 Cephamycin C
12               Avermectin B1a
13                   Adriamycin
14    Phorbol myristate acetate
15                  Thienamycin
16                Cyclosporin A
17                        FK506
18                   Trapoxin B
19                  Vincristine
20                   Colchicine
21               Trichostatin A
22                   Fumagillin
23                Staurosporine
24               Erythromycin A
25                 Streptomycin
26                Penicillin G 
27                  Sperguallin
28                    Rapamycin
29               Echinocandin B
30                 Ginkgolide B
31                   Vancomycin
32               Amphotericin B
33                    Radicicol
34           Salicylihalamide A
35                 Telomestatin
36                  Rifamycin B
37                  Apoptolidin
38               Midecamycin A1
39             Zaragozic acid A
40                Talaromycin B
41               Spongistatin 1
42                 Brevetoxin B
43                      Quinine
44                 Mycobactin S
45                Duocarmycin A
46                 Bleomycin A2
47                  Brefeldin A
48               Cytochalasin B
49                 Epothilone A
50                  Lactacystin
51              Calicheamicin 1
52                  Artemisinin
53                    Compactin
54                    Lipstatin
55           Pseudomonic acid A
56                   Daptomycin
57                     Bestatin
58                    Plaunotol
59                 Geldanamycin
Name: Name, dtype: object

    `df['smiles']`

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'smiles'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-ab79ecf9f855> in <module>
----> 1 df['smiles']

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'smiles'
`````

Comment: Can you post the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not find the column named 'smiles'
Type the command:

```
df.columns
```

See maybe there are spaces in the column name

Comment: Thank you. Actually there was an extraspace before smiles. it is working fine when I gave command df[' smiles']

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `skipinitialspace=True`, if there are spaces in front of the column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('npsmiles.csv', encoding='cp1252', skipinitialspace=True)
```